# Read files from Google Cloud Storage on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing an application with Google App Engine. I need to read PDF files from my Google Cloud Storage. Here the code:

```
String filename = "...";
BlobstoreService blobstore = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobkey = blobstore.createGsBlobKey(filename);
blobstore.serve(blobkey, httpResponse);
```

It works only if I set "Share Publicly" on the file in my bucket. How can I read the file without setting "Share Publicly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your app's service account to the bucket acls. See Section 5 of the [Google Cloud Storage Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview#Prerequisites).